# SAS: Segmenting observations in different ranges/bins

Tags: sas

I have ~4M observations of points data, and would like to segment them into different bins like the following:

```
Point_Range   Frequency
0-100          1000000
100-200        2000000
200-300        1000000
```

How would I be able to assign a range to each of the observations & output the above-like table without having to write manual "case when" or "if then" statements?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom format to map a point value to it's range representation.

Example:

```
data user_points;
  call streaminit(20201230);
  do user_id = 1 to 4e6;
    points = rand('integer', 0, 300);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format;
  value point_range
      0-<100 = ' 0  -  99'
    100-<200 = '100 - 199'
    200- 300 = '200 - 300'
  ;
run;

proc freq noprint data=user_points;
  format points point_range.;
  table points / out=bins;
run;
```

Creates data set

[image]